# HOW TO change component name Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I'm interested to rename a joomla component from:

`index.php?option=com_test&view=` to

`index.php?option=com_testest&view=`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know (yet) of an automated solution to do this. Maybe somebody else does.

The name of the component occurs in various places (class, file and folder names, the database and so on). Thus, you'd have to rename (this might not be a complete list)

- the base folder com_yourname
- all filenames which include the component name (yourname.php etc.)
- all directory names including the component name (if you want to avoid confusion with the default view names)
- all occurrences of the component name in your files (that is, mainly, PHP class names)
- the database entry holding your component name
- not to forget all links pointing to your component.

You might want to consider creating a new component and just copying the important contents...