# Want to change Joomla component name

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I want to change Joomla component name in backend. When I go to component, I see com_componentname in backend, I want to change it to com_somethingelse. Can we change it? If yes,how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what did you try until now?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766376/how-to-change-component-name-joomla?rq=1

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply, I tried to rename directories and classes and database files as well. No success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip the components install file in a folder then go though the files and rename everything that way. It'll be much easier than trying to modify the component after the fact. If you've made edits to the original component, I would still unzip and rename everything. then you'll be able to compare the files against the modified ones.

Make sure that you change the com_component.php file in the initial folder. When you change a components name, it'll look for a file with the new name. Case matters when you rename things so if you use search and replace, make it case sensitive and check every change that's make. You'll also want to edit the installer, manifest file, SQL files, language files, and all the other included files. Within the files you'll probably want to change the class names as well.

When you're done, install the component as you normally would.

As a tip: Place a comment as a marker in every file and search the system for any file with that marker so after you've installed the renamed component, you can find all the files with the marker and copy your changes to the renamed component. When you're done, you should be able to uninstall the original component.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats a perfect solution for new component however I have already installed the component and website is almost complete.

Comment: I didn't know where you were in your development stage. That's kinda the reason why I proposed doing the changes beforehand and installing the new component which shouldn't conflict if everything was done correctly, then copying your changes over. I've edited my answer to include a tip that might help with copying modifications to your renamed component.